# Auto-format on method save in Pharo

Tags: coding-style, ide, pharo

Pharo has a built-in code formatter. I want that whenever I save a method, Pharo ignores all my formatting and auto-formats the code instead. Can that be done?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure, there is a setting if you use the Refactoring Engine and OmniBrowser: In the "Settings Browser" navigate to *Refactoring Engine > Auto Format on Accept*. There is also the setting *Refactoring Engine > Auto Format on Display*, which automatically formats the code before it is displayed. The formatting settings themselves are in *Refactoring Engine > Configurable Formatter*.

Comment: If you discovered the setting "Auto Format on Accept" too late and if want to automatically format a complete package you can do so too. Select an entity of the package (e.g. a class or method) and then click in the context menu on "Refactoring scope > Package". In the new browser select "Refactor > Reformat".

Comment: On Pharo v3 the Settings Browser changed, the items you mention seem no longer to exist. It says that Formatter is `RBConfigurableFormatter`, but no auto-formatting happens when i save a method. Also i can't find in the Settings Browser and option to turn it on/off.

Answer (score 2):

I figured out a sort of hack , to deal with self formating method saves. It might come in handy.

In `NautilusUi -> compileSource: aText notifying: aController`

add this line in the begining.

```
self refactor formatSourceCode.
```

That is this will create the auto format on save functionality. Also i admit, that this is not the right way to do this, but it works for me.

```
 **compileSource: aText notifying: aController
        | source category method |
        self refactor formatSourceCode.
        source := aText asString.
        category := self selectedCategory.
        method := self selectedMethod.
        category ifNil: [ method ifNotNil: [ category := method protocol. ]. ].
        (category isNil and: [ method isNil. ])
            ifTrue: [

                source first isUppercase
                    ifTrue: [ ^ self compileAClassFrom: source notifying: aController. ].
                category := Categorizer default.
                ]
            ifFalse: [

                (category = self allLabel and: [ self selectedMethod notNil. ])
                    ifTrue: [ category := self selectedMethod protocol. ].
                ].
        self compileAMethodFromCategory: category withSource: source notifying: aController.**
```

Answer (score 0):

For OmniBrowser, I added this new method:

```
OBTextMorphEditorWithShout>>accept
"
This method did not previously exist for this class.
It is a subclass hook to auto format code on accept.
"

(ORCmdFormat on: 'TargetIsNotUsed' for: self model) execute.
super accept
```

Answer (score 0):

Not exactly what OP is asking but I think this is worth considering. When working in a project, having code formatting normalized would facilitate the life of peer-reviewers when the Pull Requests show only functional code changes without the false positives related to coding style.

I've published [PharoPackageFormatter](https://github.com/sebastianconcept/PharoPackageFormatter) precisely for this.

Here is an example of how you would use it:

```
packages := { 
    'AST-Core'.
    'AST-Core-Tests'
    }.
packages do: [ :each | PharoPackageFormatter formatPackageNamed: each ].
```